# How to set/modify value of a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable

What I have:

- contentEditable div
- React

What I want:

- Given a certain text input (in the contenteditable div), I'd like to replace the text with an image. For example, if someone types "chicken" and then enters a space, I would hypothetically replace the "chicken" portion of the text with an  of a chicken emoji.

Answer (score 0):

Contenteditable is a tricky thing, so I recommend you to use [react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable) to [prevent caret jumps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2047), plus an easy replacement (you could use whatever you want, ie regexp whatelse) could do the trick:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { html: "Hello world" };

  handleChange = evt => {
    let html = evt.target.value

    // you could take any replacement method you want
    if (html.slice(-11, html.length) === 'chicken<br>') {
      html = `${html.slice(0, -11)} ❤ <br>`
    }

    this.setState({ html });
  };

  render = () => {
    return <ContentEditable
      html={this.state.html} // innerHTML of the editable div
      disabled={false}       // use true to disable edition
      onChange={this.handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
    />
  };
};
```

You could play with it on: https://codesandbox.io/s/2x00nwnx6p